# Why in MuSiC (DoA) don't we search for minima of the inverse (pseudo)spectrum?

Tags: doa

I have started working on a Direction-of-Arrival estimation problem and I am testing various algorithms. I came across Multiple Signal Classification (MuSiC) method. In all textbooks I have looked at, the final step of the method is to search for maximums in the pseudo-spectrum given by

$$ P \left(\theta \right) = \frac{1}{a^{H}\left(\theta\right) V_{n} V_{n}^{H} a\left(\theta\right)}$$

where $P\left(\theta\right)$ is the spatial pseudo-spectrum, $a\left(\theta\right)$ is the array manifold of the array under consideration, $[ \cdot]^{H}$ denotes Hermitian transposition and $V_{n}$ is the matrix whose columns form the noise subspace (the noise eigenvectors).

Now, my question is, why should we look for maxima in $P\left(\theta\right)$ an not for minima in $\frac{1}{P\left(\theta\right)}$? Is there something I am missing here? I believe that the implementation of the algorithm could potentially benefit from avoiding this division.

Any insights and/or hints are most welcome. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's define the null-spectrum $Q(\theta)$ and pseudo-spectrum $P(\theta)$ as

$$Q(\theta) = a(\theta)^H{v_n}{v_n^H}a(\theta)$$

$$P(\theta) = \frac{1}{Q(\theta)}$$

The choice to find the maxima in $P(\theta)$ comes down to personal preference. It is more intuitive to associate a peak in a signal to some phenomenon being observed. This is especially so when reading a text, where the author is trying to teach you how the algorithm works.

You can very well search for the minima in $Q(\theta)$ instead of the maxima in $P(\theta)$ and get the same answer as can be seen in the example below

[image]

[image]

Nothing is stopping you from using the minima. In general there is no significant advantage to using either except for avoiding division operations and potential divide-by-zero, which usually fine in real systems where some kind of noise is present. Still, certain systems and their implementation can make using one over the other more appropriate.